# Store Var Into Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Hi guys I'm aware that this question has been asked before however none of the answers seem to solve this issue.

I have this simple jQuery code:

```
var productName = jQuery('.product-name h1').html;
```

I'd like to store the `productName` variable into local storage so I can use the variable when the page is refreshed.

Can anybody show me how I can make this happen?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: What is your progress?

Comment: when you say variable, do you mean the jQuery object containing the actual elements, as it is now, or just say the HTML within them? You can't save the actual object because the elements are destroyed when the page is unloaded. Besides, `localStorage` can only store strings.

Comment: The [storage interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#storage-2) only allows a `DOMString` (which is a string) as value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add new item to Web Storage API:

```
// First method
localStorage.setItem('VARIABLE_NAME', 'VARIABLE CONTENT');
// Second method
localStorage.VARIABLE_NAME = 'VARIABLE_CONTENT';
```

To retrieve value from Web Storage API:

```
localStorage.getItem('VARIABLE_NAME');
// or
localStorage.VARIABLE_NAME;
```

To store object, you need change Javascript Object to JSON notation:

```
localStorage.setItem('VARIABLE_NAME', JSON.stringify(JS_OBJECT));
```

Reference:

[1. Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

[2. `JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

After first comment, I think the proper way to do is:

```
Session.prototype.setDOMObject = function(name, object) {
    Session.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(object));
}

Session.prototype.getDOMObject = function(name) {
    var object = JSON.parse(Session.getItem(name));

    return $(object.selector);
}
```

This way, it stores a *selector* and it retrieves an object created using this selector. But it doesn't store the state of DOM element. If you want to save the state of DOM object (inside HTML), then you need to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

Comment: How is this supposed to work with an jQuery object (`jQuery('.product-name h1')`)?

Answer (score 1):

```
localStorage.productName = jQuery('.product-name h1').html()
```

Comment: `jQuery('.product-name h1') !== jQuery('.product-name h1').html()` and there is no evidence in the question that the markup returned by `.html()` should be stored in localStorage

Comment: @Andreas: Im guessing that's what he meant bc it looks like he wants the title value